# Что за выражение (1, S::x)?

Tags: c++, стандарт

**Что за выражение?**

**(1, S::x)**

Взято из след. кода:

```
struct S {
    static const int x = 0; // static data member
    // a definition outside of class is required if it is odr-used
};
const int& f(const int& r);

int n = b ? (1, S::x) // S::x is not odr-used here
          : f(S::x);  // S::x is odr-used here: a definition is required
```

Comment: Странная запись. Зачем тут оператор запятая я не понимаю. Может учебный пример на что-то?)

Comment: Какое-то пространство имён его собственное? Ну как std::

Comment: есть пара вариантов. К примеру, там был вызов функции. Но в процессе "колхозного рефакторинга" (найти-заменить), имя потерялось. Но так как оно компилилось, то не увидели. Второй вариант - кто то решил просто усложить код (ну что бы круто выглядело)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пытаюсь навести порядок. Прежде всего, это код из C++ standard: http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr и cpp-reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition
Код не имеет никакого практического значения, кроме демонстрации данной концепции C++. Фрагменты стандарта с моими вставками:

A non-overloaded function `const int &f(const int &r)` whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression `f(S::x)`, if selected by overload resolution when referred to from a potentially-evaluated expression, is odr-used `Функция вызывается или ее адрес используется`.

The set of potential results of an expression e is defined as follows:
...
If e is a comma expression `(1, S::x)`, the set contains the potential results of the right operand `S::x`.
...

Итак: `(1, S::x)` S::x используется для оценки выражения `(1, S::x)`. Оценка прозводится во время компиляции, при этом не выполняется ни одно из условий  `value is read or written, its address is taken`, поэтому выражение компилируется (S::x is not ODR-used).

С другой стороны, в выражении `f(S::x)` функция `f` is odr-used, (см. параграф non-overloaded function), поэтому требуется ее вызвать, результат - linker error, function f is undefined.

И еще: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other Other operators, Built-in comma operator. Эта часть самая простая:

`E1 ,E2 - E1 is evaluated, its result is discarded,expression result is E2`

Answer (score 2):

`(1,S::x)` - просто использован оператор "запятая", причем первая его часть - `1` - ничего не выполняет.

Так что можно оставить только обращение к статическому члену класса (структуры) `S::x`.

Скобка нужна, потому что приоритет оператора `,` самый низкий, ниже, чем у тернарного оператора.

Зачем это извращение и почему не написать просто

```
int n = b ? S::x : f(S::x);
```

не вижу. Никаких тонкостей, связанных со ссылочностью, мне лично тоже не видно. Возможно, ошибаюсь - но тогда это какая-то слишком тонкая тонкость :)

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*

Comment: вы [вот это](http://harmful.cat-v.org/software/c++/I_did_it_for_you_all) видели? Что думаете?

Comment: @avp Думаю, что это шутка - такая же, как и шутка о языке С, разрабатывавшемся якобы специально таким, чтоб никто не мог на нем программировать... Мне куда больше нравится другая цитата от Страуструпа - только вот точно не помню источник - что чтобы хорошо программировать на С++, не обязательно знать **все** тонкости языка...

Comment: Harry, ну, шуткой тут может быть только приписывание Страуструпу  этих слов. Т.е. хорошо программировать на крестах, конечно, можно (если  использовать поменьше его свойств, отличных от Си)